# Find OS Name/Version using JScript

Tags: windows, javascript

I have to maintain a server-side script written in JScript (NOT Javascript) that needs to discover the OS of the system that it's running on. How can I do this correctly and robustly?

Comment: This question shows us how to detect the OS version.
(Hopefully it will be indexed better now.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/jscript/os/version/ostveb01.mspx?mfr=true) for all the different system information you can get.

Here's some sample code that I threw together based on that webpage:

```
var wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 0x10;
var wbemFlagForwardOnly = 0x20;
var objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2");
var colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem", "WQL",
                                      wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly);

var enumItems = new Enumerator(colItems);
var objItem = enumItems.item();
WScript.Echo("Caption: " + objItem.Caption);
```